lme4 Inconsistency
We aim to model how reaction times (RT) differ between groups in a fully between-subjects design. We also expect item difficulty to affect responses, and to interact with group. Each subject (n=120) is entirely nested within one of five groups. With 200 observations per subject, we plan to include a random intercept for each subject to account for the non-independence of observations. However, we want this random intercept to account for the nesting of subjects within groups to avoid confounding our main fixed effect of group. Each item is fully nested within one difficulty level, and should follow the same nesting strategy.
To account for this nesting, we have used the following syntax: (1|Group:Subject). Robert Long's answer here (Lmer model syntax for a combination of crossed and nested random effects) suggests that this syntax is not necessary, and that instead (1|Subject) suffices, as R should automatically know that data are nested.
However, testing this in two models as shown below demonstrates different results, see below.
Data and script can be found here:  https://osf.io/g3wqh/, and are also embedded below. Data are structured as follows:
Subject Group RT Item Diff
1 A 1547 43 3  
1 A 1432 85 7  
... Etc 
120 C 1048 23 2  

Code as follows:
#Packages----
library(lme4)

#Preliminaries----
data <- read.csv("lme4 data.csv", header = TRUE)
attach(data)

data$Group <- as.factor(data$Group)
data$Subject <- as.factor(data$Subject)
data$Item <- as.factor(data$Item)
data$Diff <- as.integer(data$Diff)

#Models

Model1 <- lmer(RT~Group*Diff + (1|Diff:Item) + (1|Group:Subject),data=data, lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), REML=F, na.action=na.omit)
anova(Model1,type=3) 
summary(Model1)

Results:
Factor Pr(>F)
Group 7.643e-05
Diff 1.274e-09
Group:Diff 3.346e-16

Model2 <- lmer(RT~Group*Diff + (1|Item) + (1|Subject),data=data, lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), REML=F, na.action=na.omit)
anova(Model2,type=3) 
summary(Model2)

Results:
Factor Pr(>F)
Group 8.300e-05
Diff 1.350e-09
Group:Diff 5.308e-06

As you can see, the two models produce different results even though they shouldn't. There are no warning messages. lme4 is up to date. Any explanations very welcome.

Your second model also removes the Diff:Item interaction from the random effects, I would expect that to give different results unless these are also unique.

Given that Diff is an integer and used as such in the fixed effects, I wonder if you perhaps wanted random slopes, i.e. (Diff|Item), but that doesn't make much sense either when you have only one Diff per item.

The important part of Robert Longs answer was

because group is coded uniquely across district

Item is not uniquely coded across Diff, to be exact 28 are in two different ones:
library(tidyverse)

data %>% group_by(Item) %>% 
  summarise(diffs_per_item = n() - sum(duplicated(Diff)), diffs_agg = paste0(sort(unique(Diff)), collapse = "/")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(diffs_per_item)) %>% filter(diffs_per_item > 1)

result:
# A tibble: 28 × 3
   Item  diffs_per_item diffs_agg
   <fct>          <int> <chr>    
 1 131                2 3/5      
 2 132                2 3/6      
 3 133                2 5/6      
 4 135                2 5/7      
 5 136                2 5/7      
 6 137                2 5/6      
 7 138                2 6/7      
 8 139                2 6/7      
 9 140                2 5/6      
10 141                2 5/7      
# ℹ 18 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

You can also see the in the summary of Model 1 with
groups:  Diff:Item, 227; Group:Subject, 120


Thank you very much for your help, we have identified a software error due to this. Thank you again

@JamesScott Glad I could help. If this answered your question, please accept it. I like seeing the green on my user page:)
